# How to do block select in Colab (also called vertical select / multiline edit)

Tags: select, block, google-colaboratory, multiline

It is feasible in Jupyter/Sublime text editor, and other places.
How to do it within Colab?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation/shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Mouse:

- Press Shift+Alt and then use the mouse

With Keyboard:

- Press Shift+Alt and then use the arrow keys to move*

* In my system Shift+Alt+Left/Right will change desktop. But I found that in **Colab**, once I go up/down as needed (creating the multi-line selection) then I can release **Alt** and continue only with **Shift** and move horizontally as needed.

[image: Block selection in Colab]

Bonus:

- Q: How to move up/down the selected text easily?
- A:

  - If you just press Alt+Up/Down, the line you are in will move Up/Down
  - If you select some text and press Alt+Up/Down, that block will move Up/Down

[image: Moving selection up/down in Colab]